# How to disable button if no checkbox is selected

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, model-view-controller, input

I got the following angular template:

```
<tr ng-repeat="user in users">
    <td><input type="checkbox"></td>
    <td>{{user.username}}</td>
    <td>{{user.apiKey}}</td>
    <td>{{user.apiSecret}}</td>
</tr>
...
<button type="button" class="btn btn-danger"><i class="fa fa-trash-o"></i></button>
```

How can I disable the button if no checkbox is checked but enable it whenever one or more checkboxes in the table are checked?

And how can I determine which table entry was checked and access the user-data?

Answer (score 5):

The Angular way is to use `ng-disabled`. As an example you can use this:

```
ng-disabled="!checked"
```

*The ! means to do the opposite, so !true == false = true*

**Full Example:**

```
<td>
   <input type="checkbox" ng-model="checked"
</td> 

<button class="btn btn-danger" ng-disabled="!checked"><i class="fa fa-trash-o"></i>Submit</button>
```

**Read more on ng-disabled here:**

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngDisabled

**What is HTML attribute `checked`?**

> The checked attribute is a boolean attribute.
>
> When present, it specifies that an  element should be
>   pre-selected (checked) when the page loads.
>
> The checked attribute can be used with  and
>   `<input type="radio">`.

[CODEPEN DEMO](http://codepen.io/Gothburz/pen/zvmwVK)

Comment: What is "checked" and where does it come from?

Comment: That doesn't seem to work for me:
`<td><input type="checkbox" ng-model="checked"></td>`
`<button class="btn btn-danger" ng-disabled="!checked"><i class="fa fa-trash-o"></i></button>`
But nothing happens when I check it.

Comment: there is something else wrong then, have you called ``ng-app``? I cant see the rest of your code to tell you. I updated my pen to demonstrate it's working.

Answer (score 1):

You could add the `checked` state to the user and check at every checkbox change if there is still one user selected.

Checking can be done with `angular.forEach`, with a for loop or with underscore.js (if you'd like to use it). 
During that loop you can also create the array of checked users.

Please have a look at the demo below or in thid [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/awolf2904/axppacmy/).

```js
angular.module('demoApp', [])
    .controller('MainController', MainController);

function MainController($scope) {
    $scope.users = [{
        username: 'John',
        apiKey: '1234',
        apiSecret: '2345'
    }, {
        username: 'Jane',
        apiKey: '234',
        apiSecret: '24'
    }];
    $scope.checkedUsers = [];
    
    $scope.checkButtonState = function() {
     /* with underscore.js
        $scope.checkedUsers = _.where($scope.users, {check: true});
        $scope.enableButton = _.chain($scope.checkedUsers)
            .pluck('check').some().value();
        */
        $scope.checkedUsers = [];
        angular.forEach($scope.users, function(user) {
         if ( user.check ) {
                $scope.checkedUsers.push(user);
            }
        });
        
        $scope.enableButton = $scope.checkedUsers.length > 0;
    };
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.4.0/css/font-awesome.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.4.7/angular.js"></script>
<div ng-app="demoApp" ng-controller="MainController">
    <table>
        <tr ng-repeat="user in users">
            <td>
                <input 
                       ng-model="user.check"
                       ng-change="checkButtonState()"
                       type="checkbox">
            </td>
            <td>{{user.username}}</td>
            <td>{{user.apiKey}}</td>
            <td>{{user.apiSecret}}</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
        
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger"  ng-disabled="!enableButton"><i class="fa fa-trash-o"></i>
    </button>
        {{checkedUsers}}
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

In a non-angularJS example (vs. @GothBurz's answer, which is more elegant but less intuitive):

jQuery:

```
$("input:checkbox").change(function() {     // every time a checkbox changes
    $("button").attr("disabled", "true");   // start button disabled
    $("input:checkbox:checked").each(function() {
        $("button").removeAttr("disabled"); // if any checkbox checked, make button enabled
    });
});
```

See a working example [on JSFiddle.net](http://jsfiddle.net/wnxmr0x3/).

Or, for a longer, non-jQuery example, see [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wnxmr0x3/5/).

Comment: But jQuery wasn't tagged in the question; unless jQuery's automatically required for angular.js? I've not used angular so I honestly don't know.

Comment: @DavidThomas This can easily be converted to plain JS. I'll provide another example.

Comment: how is using an entire jQuery function vs a single line of angular more elegant?

Comment: @DavidThomas happier now?

Comment: Well, sort of, I suppose; except you've answered with a non-tagged library and left the only part of your answer that might apply in a linked page, where as soon as the external resource dies, falls over or gets reorganised, it becomes useless. I'd be happier if you included that externally-linked script into your answer and explained how it works. But I'm not the arbiter of quality, if you think it's a valid answer then go with it.

Comment: much happier xP, nice jquery solution by the wy! I stole it and saved it as a gist.